# Dropdown selection navigation to different page with dropdown values; Asp.Net + Javascript

Tags: asp.net, javascript

I want to access drop down menu's variable in java script on change event, here is my code

```
 <asp:DropDownList ID="DropDownList1" runat="server" onchange="document.location.href = url_Lookbook;" >
        <asp:ListItem Value="0">hello</asp:ListItem>
        <asp:ListItem Value="1">world</asp:ListItem>
        </asp:DropDownList>
```

here is the script coding:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var url_Lookbook = "http://microsoft.com";
</script>
```

My question is how do I pass down value=0 or value = 1 to different page, any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you wrote it as a javascript function, it would be simpler

```
 <asp:DropDownList ID="DropDownList1" runat="server" onchange="navFromList(this.value);" >
        <asp:ListItem Value="0">hello</asp:ListItem>
        <asp:ListItem Value="1">world</asp:ListItem>
</asp:DropDownList>

<script type="text/javascript">
    function navFromList( qsParam )
    {
        document.location.href = "http://microsoft.com?arg=" + qsParam;
        return false;
    }
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

This is how I do it, completely in server side code.  You don't have to use javascript (if you aren't required to)

```
                    <asp:DropDownList ID="ddlGlobalDestinations" runat="server" OnSelectedIndexChanged="ddlGlobalDestinations_SelectedIndexChanged" AutoPostBack="true">
                        <asp:ListItem Text="StackOverflow" Value="http://www.stackoverflow.com"></asp:ListItem>
                        <asp:ListItem Text="Google" Value="http://www.google.com/"></asp:ListItem>
                    <asp:ListItem Text="Microsoft" Value="http://www.microsoft.com/"></asp:ListItem>                    
                    </asp:DropDownList>
```

here is the c# code-behind

```
protected void ddlGlobalDestinations_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Response.Redirect(ddlGlobalDestinations.SelectedValue, true);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

onchange="document.location.href = url_Lookbook + '?param=' + this.value;" appears to work in FF3 and IE7.